# How to redirect page after submit form success with Nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxtjs

In the following code, I want to redirect the page to '/contact/success' when submit is successful. How to do it with axios and nuxt?

```js
  methods: {
    async sendMessage() {
      try {
        // Set status to 'pending'
        this.status = 'pending'

        const config = {
          method: 'POST',
          url: `${this.$config.strapiURL}/contacts`,
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${this.$config.strapiToken}`,
          },
          data: {
            name: this.formValues.name,
            subject: this.formValues.subject,
            email: this.formValues.email,
            message: this.formValues.message,
          },
        }
        const data = await this.$axios(config)
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('error', error)
        // Set status to 'error'
        this.status = 'error'
      } finally {
        // Set status to 'success'
        this.status = 'success'
        // Clear form
        this.$formulate.reset('contact')
      }
    },
},
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Inside your component you have access to `this.$router`

So you can easily do:

```
this.$router.push('/')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [programmatic navigation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html).

```
this.$router.push('/contact/success')
```

in your success callback on your axios request